# first time mining. stuck at generating ethash

Tags: mining

I tried using phoenixminer and claymore. I am already in dmz mode and av is off.
I can connect to the ethermine pool but stuck at generating ethash

```
CUDA version: 11.0, CUDA runtime: 8.0
Available GPUs for mining:
GPU1: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti (pcie 101), CUDA cap. 7.5, 11 GB VRAM, 68 CUs
Nvidia driver version: 461.40
Eth: the pool list contains 2 pools (2 from command-line)
Eth: primary pool: us1.ethermine.org:4444
Starting GPU mining
Eth: Connecting to ethash pool us1.ethermine.org:4444 (proto: EthProxy)
GPU1: 34C 17% 66W
GPUs power: 66.5 W
Listening for CDM remote manager at port 3333 in read-only mode
Eth: Can't resolve host us1.ethermine.org:4444 - No such host is known
Eth: Reconnecting in 5 seconds...
Eth: Connecting to ethash pool us1.ethermine.org:4444 (proto: EthProxy)
Eth: Connected to ethash pool us1.ethermine.org:4444 (2606:4700:90:0:b886:9f1:5c3e:5711)
Eth: New job #7c0ee9e7 from us1.ethermine.org:4444; diff: 4000MH
GPU1: Starting up... (0)
GPU1: Generating ethash light cache for epoch #395
```

Tried looking for any solution.Didn't find any.

Thanks

Comment: Try asking in r/EtherMining on reddit.

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve the problem, but you can use the IP instead of the name. It worked for me.